# Tried to implement lists as dictionary keys within algorithm, what's a quick solution?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, hashable

I am trying to implement the Apriori algorithm... http://codeding.com/articles/apriori-algorithm in Python.

The highest level data structuring goes something like this:

```
frequentItemSets[ k-level : itemSetDictionary]
                            |
                            |__
                               itemSetDictionary[ listOfItems : supportValueOfItems]
                                                  |
                                                  |__
                                                     list of integers, sorted lexicographically
```

I need to keep track of an arbitrary number of sets, the cardinality (k-level) of those sets, and a value that I calculate for each of those sets. I thought that using a list for all of the sets would be a good idea as they maintain order and are iterable. I tried to use lists as the keys within the itemSetDictionary, as you can see above, but now I see that iterable data structures are not allowed to be keys wihtin Python dictionaries.

I am trying to figure out the quickest way to fix this issue. I know that I can just create some classes so that the keys are now objects, and not iterable data structures, but I feel like that would take a lot of time for me to change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary keys must be [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable), which usable requires them to be [immutable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-immutable).  Whether they are iterable is immaterial.

In this particular case, you probably want to use [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s as keys.

Comment: I see that Tuples are immutable and are ordered, I imagine tuples would work? I need the item sets to provide an order to their elements.

Comment: @Gthoma2: Yes, tuples would work as well, also e.g. tuples of frozensets.

Comment: tuples only work to the extent that they also contain immutable data structures. i.e., `(({1,2},{3,4}))` still cannot be used as a key, even though it is a tuple, since the tuple contains mutable sets.

Comment: Yes -- you can use a frozen set. You can also do `str({ ur set })` and use the string of the set as a key since strings are hashable.